# How much JavaScript knowledge do I need before I venture onto Node.js?

Tags: node.js

Please forgive me if questions of this nature are not allowed here. I pored over the rules and didn't find anything on it.

I am currently learning JavaScript thoroughly because Node.js interests me greatly. I have watched a few video tutorials on Lynda.com, done the CodeSchool challenges, as well as scripted a few things in the past.

So I thought I was ready for a beginner's lesson in Node.js.

I crashed and burned at the "Hello World" part.

Here's apparently what that code looks like:

```
var http = require('http');
var myServer = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type" : "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello");
  response.end();
});

myServer.listen(3000);
```

Ahhh, ummmm, okay... I have no idea what's going on there (methods I've never seen, curly braces in strange places). Not asking either, so don't get me wrong. **What I'm asking for is some sort of a guideline for when I'm ready to even begin with the easiest of tutorials regarding Node.js.** If a "Hello World" is *that* hard, will I ever be able to understand the rest of it?

Comment: Some guide about javascript functions and http post/get requests maybe would help. Giving a function as parameter is just a common thing in javascript, don't get surprised. Angular.js has same nature on their usage, for example.

Comment: Not confused about the function as parameter part. Confused about why "request" is there if it is never used and what "writeHead" and "Content-Type" is.

Comment: it's hello word program so no need to do anything with request hence it is not mentioned in the code anywhere. If you ask why it is there, - http.createServer calls the callback like that.

Comment: Maybe you had bad tutorial for your hello world. http://www.theprojectspot.com/tutorial-post/Node-js-for-beginners-part-1-hello-world/2 has this all explained, starting from " Let's take a closer look at our code." and below ;)

Comment: @mico Thanks! Yeah, Lynda.com usually has good or even great tutorials but this specific guy (no names named) seemingly likes to rush things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> methods I've never seen

As with any software engineering endeavor, you should learn to read the documentation. The http module documentation can be found here: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html.  These are the instructions you need to use it correctly.  Without reading this, you will never have any hope of succeeding.

> curly braces in strange places

These are part of `function` and `Object` definitions.  You must first be acquainted with both, as they are the backbone of any JavaScript app.  Functions are more powerful in JavaScript than you'd expect with many other languages.

> If a "Hello World" is that hard

You're actually doing a lot more than a "Hello World".  Try running `node` from the command line and typing in `console.log("Hello World")`.  "Hello World" should show in your console.  What you're actually doing is beyond a "Hello World" app, actually writing the server code that handles HTTP requests.  In order to understand this, you should first learn about HTTP.

**Advice**

I would recommend learning HTML and in-browser JavaScript first.  You will get visual feedback when your function runs instead of having to understand some more advanced concepts such as HTTP, bash, and servers.  You'd be surprised how advanced you can make a website without needing any server-side code, such as node.

Comment: Ah okay. I thought these were all regular JavaScript methods since the tutorial brought them up without even explaining them further. Still confused about some parts but at least that clears something up. And yes, of course I am aware of JavaScript's power, my goal is to learn so much that I can get comfortable starting to learn Node.js. :)

Comment: @Yeats In my opinion you need to read some good Javascript book first before diving into node.js

Answer (score 1):

As my comment says, http://www.theprojectspot.com/tutorial-post/Node-js-for-beginners-part-1-hello-world/2 is a link to a better tutorial, where all this is explained quite well.

Since link only answers aren't eligible for this site, here are the main points of the tutorial you had most difficult to understand:

http request handler gets its arguments request and response for http service, which are generated automagically for every time someone reaches the server askig data. Object request is the one than has the question for us and response is the place for our answer.

We respond to any request to given port (3000) the sentence "Hello" by altering the response object given to us in the function. The number 200 means OK and with the Content type they are the meta data to the protocol http that it gets our data through and understood.

Node.js is about being a full protocol stack for a website, that's why the underlying techniques are so much present. HTTP by the way stands for Hyper Text Transfer Protocol, so that's quite important part of every site. You even right it to every url. Ftp is its alternative for instance.